# Mutate ifelse on a vector

Tags: r

Let's say I have this data frame:

```
set.seed(2)
df <- iris[c(1:5,51:55,101:105),]

df_long <- gather(df, key = "flower_att", value = "measurement",
       Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)

df_long$setosa_sub <-sample(5,size = 60, replace = TRUE)
df_long$versicolor_sub <-sample(5,size = 60, replace = TRUE)
df_long$virginica_sub <-sample(5,size = 60, replace = TRUE)
df_long$sub_q<-0
```

Now I want to copy a value to sub_q variable based on Species variable and sub values.
I know how to do it one by one:

```
df_long2 <- df_long %>%  
  mutate(sub_q =ifelse(Species =="setosa", setosa_sub,sub_q)) %>%
  mutate(sub_q =ifelse(Species =="versicolor", versicolor_sub,sub_q)) %>%
  mutate(sub_q =ifelse(Species =="virginica", virginica_sub,sub_q))
```

But I can't figure out what is the right way to apply on a vector of the Species values instead.

```
species_vector <- c("setosa","versicolor","virginica")
```

I'm actually not sure if I need to make new function or just loop it somehow. Hope it's make sense...

Comment: Do you specifically need to pass your condition as a vactor or is you question about how to combine the three if_else commands into one? If the latter, then please have a look at the `case_when` function, which does exactly this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the way you are doing it. Another way, using an apply function (`sapply` in this case) would work like this:

```
# a helper function to find the right value for the xth row
get_correct_sub <- function(x){ 
   col_name = paste0(df_long$Species[x],'_sub')
   df_long[[ col_name ]][x] }
# apply each row index to the helper function
df_long2 = df_long
df_long2$sub_q = sapply(1:nrow(df_long), get_correct_sub)
```

The helper function adds "_sub" to the species name, treats that as a column name, and then gets the value for that column.

Comment: The reason I need it is because on my real dataframe I have a lot more sub questions to match. Your solution was exactly what I needed.
Thank you so much! ^-^

Comment: @Rana Glad it helped. Please select an accepted answer so others with the same question can find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `datastep()` solution.  I created a vector lookup to map the Species to the desired column, then step through the data row by row and assign the value using the lookup. `data` is the input dataset and `n.` is the current row number:

```
library(libr)

# Create vector lookup
species_vector <- c("setosa" = "setosa_sub", "versicolor" = "versicolor_sub", "virginica" = "virginica_sub")


# Step through data row by row, and assign value using lookup
df_long2 <- df_long %>%
  datastep({
  
    sub_q <- data[n., species_vector[Species]]
  
  })
```